# Alternating between x86 and arm java builds

Tags: sdkman

I have a need to alternate between and x86 zulu java build and the arm build. Is there a way to do this? I am running on an apple M1. I've set my terminal to open using rosetta I have the config set to true for sdkman. I've then installed the zulu 21 but I still see the arm version. Is this not possible anymore with sdkman? I've found this [article](https://itnext.io/how-to-install-x86-and-arm-jdks-on-the-mac-m1-apple-silicon-using-sdkman-872a5adc050d) but it doesn't seem to work for me.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
 % cat ~/.sdkman/etc/config
sdkman_auto_answer=false
sdkman_auto_complete=true
sdkman_auto_env=false
sdkman_beta_channel=false
sdkman_checksum_enable=true
sdkman_colour_enable=true
sdkman_curl_connect_timeout=7
sdkman_curl_max_time=10
sdkman_debug_mode=false
sdkman_insecure_ssl=false
sdkman_rosetta2_compatible=true
sdkman_selfupdate_feature=true
% cat `which java` | file -
/dev/stdin: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
~ % java -version
openjdk version "21" 2023-09-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu21.28+85-CA (build 21+35)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu21.28+85-CA (build 21+35, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't looked at the git history, but right now there is no reference to `sdkman_rosetta2_compatible` within the code, so it must have been dropped as it was temporary from what that article alludes to.

Interestingly enough, I did see the env `SDKMAN_PLATFORM` in there being used when downloading SDKs, which is actually being set in `~/.sdkman/var/platform` and has a value of `darwinarm64` (on m1). With that env I am able to list and install x86 SDKs on my m1 with the below:

```
SDKMAN_PLATFORM=darwin sdk list java
SDKMAN_PLATFORM=darwin sdk install java 11.0.9-zulu
sdk use java 11.0.9-zulu
cat `which java` | file -
```

Which will output the following

```
/dev/stdin: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

If that doesn't work then try flushing the cache (`sdk flush tmp`) and then try again.